# Retrieving the sender of PyQt4 QLabel mousepressevent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm programming an interface in PyQt4 and I am using QLabels and making them clickable using the mousepressevent function. I have multiple labels (signals) that have the same mousepressevent slot. Here is the gist of what I'm trying to do.

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
         lbl1=QtGui.QLabel(self)
         lbl2=QtGui.QLabel(self)
         lbl1.mousePressEvent=self.exampleMousePress
         lbl2.mousePressEvent=self.exampleMousePress


    def exampleMousePress(self,event):
         print "The sender is: " + sender().text()
```

The problem is that the sender function is not working here. Is there a way to get the event sender in the exampleMousePress function?

Thank you all!

Comment: Events are not the same as signals.  They are two separate systems.  Signals have senders.  Events don't.  What widget would you expect to receive here as the sender?

Comment: Can't you use a button for sending signals? You can change the button's style sheet to make it look flat like a label.

Comment: For this program, I specifically needed a label, not a button. And thanks for the clarification Brendan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event-filtering](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to do this:

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl1.installEventFilter(self)
        lbl2.installEventFilter(self)    

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print "The sender is:", source.text()
        return super(Example, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```